# How to upload zip files to custom appcenter app via fastlane?

Tags: ios, fastlane, visual-studio-app-center

I needed to upload an iOS simulator build to appcenter.
Only option was to create a "Custom" type appcenter app and upload as a zip file. Uploading works fine manually.
But when I use following appcenter api for fastlane it's seems not supporting this.

```
 appcenter_upload(api_token: <token>,
                 owner_name: <name>,
                 owner_type: <user>,
                 app_name: <appname>,
                 file: <zip file path>,
                 notify_testers: true,
                 destinations: "*",
                 app_os: 'Custom',
                 app_platform: 'Custom',
                 release_notes: <release_notes>)
```

> ### Extension not supported: '.zip'. Supported formats for platform 'ios':
> .ipa The current operation might fail, trying anyway...
>
> --- Step: appcenter_upload ---
> ------------------------------ Error creating app 409: {"error"=>{"code"=>"Conflict", "message"=>"Validation error"}}

Does anyone has similar experiences ?

Also there are no samples for "Custom" type uploads in App center forums.

Comment: Have you tried microsofts official fastlane plugin? https://github.com/microsoft/fastlane-plugin-appcenter